# Add several columns to a RDD through other RDDs in scala

Tags: scala, join, rdd

I have 4 RDDs with the same key but different columns. And I want to attached them. I thought in perform a fullOuterJoin because, even if the ids are not matched I want the complete register.

Maybe this is easier with dataframes (taking into account not to lose registers)? But until now I have the following code:

```
var final_agg = rdd_agg_1.fullOuterJoin(rdd_agg_2).fullOuterJoin(rdd_agg_2).fullOuterJoin(rdd_agg_4).map {
    case (id, // TODO this case to format the resulting rdd)
}
```

If I have this rdds:

```
rdd1              rdd2          rdd3          rdd4
id  field1    id  field2      id  field3     id  field4
 1    2        1    2          1    2         2    3
 2    5        5    1
```

So the resulting rdd would have the following form:

```
     rdd
id        field1       field2        field3     field4
 1           2            2            2          3
 2           5            -            -          -
 5           -            1            -          -
```

EDIT:

This is the RDD that I want to format in the case:

```
     org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (Option[(Option[(Option[Int], Option[Int])], Option[Int])], Option[String]))]
```

Comment: What's the resulting format from your operation, and what format are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want a RDD with these columns: id, field1,field2,field3 and field4.

Comment: It would help if you showed the result of doing the outer joins, maybe print out a few elements from `final_agg`?

Comment: I have updated the question with the format of the RDD by console. I don't have more results because it doesn't compile. Tell me if you need more information.